# Why do we have to specify the datatype of each formal argument separately?

Tags: c

If we can declare more than one variable like this:

```
int i, j, k;
```

then why do I get an error when I write in formal arguments:

```
void fun(int i, j, k)
```

instead of:

```
void fun(int i, int j, int k)
```

Comment: Because of the language specification.

Comment: Because of the pre-historic behaviour of C without prototypes, and the design decision made by C++ to not allow the syntax you suggest.  Also, given the current function definition `void f1(int i1, int i2, double d1, double d2)`, how would you write it in your variant syntax?  `void f1(int i1, i2; double d1, d2)`?  Or would you use a comma where I placed a semicolon?  Or something else?

Comment: The first line declares *three* variables, the second only one. The correct analogy would be something like `int a = 1, * b = &a, foo(char, char);`

Comment: btw you should avoid declaring more than one variable in a statement it makes for error prone code e.g. `int* i,j; `

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because this is not how C syntax works. Parameter declarations are different from variable declarations in several ways, e.g.

```
void fun(int i, double x);
```

vs.

```
int i, double x;            // syntax error
```

While the syntax could have been extended to allow the form you tried (which is allowed by, e.g., Go with its `func fun(i, j, k int)`, the standard committee decided not to do this, presumably because it would be confusing in the face of old-style ("K&R", pre-1989) parameter syntax, which was still supported in ANSI C89/ISO C90 for backward compatibility.

```
void fun(i, j)  // K&R syntax: implicitly int i, int j
{
}

void fun(i, p)
    int *p;     // int i implicit!
{
}

// What's this? double i? double *i? Mixed K&R/ANSI syntax with implicit int i?
void fun(double *x, i)
{
}
```